# Exercise about stack overflow

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I'm trying to learn stack overflows but I have a problem with an exercise. In the vulnerable program the part of the code that must receive my shellcode is:

```
 int array[8];
 index = (int) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
 value = (int) strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 16);
 array[index] = value;
```

I found easily the index of the array to use to overwrite RET. Then I tried to find the offset of the return address in the vulnerable program like this:

```
./victim 12 $(printf "%0512x" 0)
```

I tried a lot of different lengths, but at every possible length I get a segmentation fault. This is weird, because my book says that I should be able to get a segmentation fault only where the saved return address is. 
I'm a beginner, so probably I'm doing some basic mistake. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: Also, why does the length of input string have anything to do with this?  `strtol` will always interpret it as `0`.

Comment: The book is "The Shellcoder's Handbook" by Anley, Heasman, Lindner, Richarte. I found in the book the indication to try different lengths to find the offset, but if the string will be always interpreted as 0 how can I get around this problem?

Comment: Something else is going on that you're not showing us.  If you create a simple main() that only does the code that you show, it does not core dump.  Show a minimal full program that reliably produces your failure.  Run it under gdb and get a backtrace (e.g. `gdb ./victim corefile`, then run `bt`).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a segmentation fault because you're only providing your program with a single argument, but yet you're calling `strtoul` on `argv[2]`, which is a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: There was an error in the post, when I tried the exercise I used two arguments. I edited the post and now it's right.